# How to set initial value in the form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Hey guys how can i set initial value in my form field, let say the user click "BidForm" in the search form, i want the BidForm value will be the value of ProjectName in the other form...

here's my code in my search views

```
def search_views(request):
    project_list = ProjectNameInviToBid.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    if query:
        project_list = project_list.filter(ProjectName__icontains=query)

    context = {
        'project_list': project_list
    }
    return render(request, 'content/search_views.html', context)
```

and my other views

```
def project_name_details(request, sid):

    majordetails = ProjectNameInviToBid.objects.get(id=sid)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = invitoBidForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.fields['ProjectName'].initial = majordetails
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'File has been Uploaded')
    else:
        form = invitoBidForm()

    args = {
        'majordetails': majordetails,
        'form': form

    }
    return render(request,'content/invitoBid/bacadmininvitoBid.html', args)
```

my form.py

```
class invitoBidForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = InviToBid
        fields = ('ProjectName','NameOfFile', 'Contract_No', 'Bid_Opening',
                  'Pre_Bid_Conference', 'Non_Refundable_Bidder_Fee',
                  'Delivery_Period',
                  'Pdf_fileinvi',)
```

and my models.py

```
class ProjectNameInviToBid(models.Model):
    ProjectName = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Project Name', null=True)
    DateCreated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ProjectName


class InviToBid(models.Model):
    today = date.today()
    ProjectName = models.ForeignKey('ProjectNameInviToBid', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    NameOfFile = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Name of File')
    Contract_No = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Contract No')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.NameOfFile
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I shall praise your documentation. Most people fail to provide the important code.

You can add something like this to your code here that will do what you require.

**An example from my own code**

```
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.user.is_authenticated:
        study = Study.objects.get(pk=studyID)
        form = ContactForm(initial={'from_email': request.user.email, 'subject': "Study: " + study.name ,'message': study_message.format(request.user.get_short_name(), request.user.get_full_name())})
```

**How you should change your code**

Change your code in your `other views` from this:

```
else:
        form = invitoBidForm()
```

to

```
else:
        form = invitoBidForm(initial={'ProjectName': <wherever your project name comes from>})
```